# Rails 4.2.6 disable MD5 for FIPS compliance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fips

How does one disable MD5 and other non-FIPS compliant algorithms in Rails 4.2.6 and Ruby 2.2+?

> Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2016-04-12 11:00:52 -0400 Processing by
>   Rails::WelcomeController#index as ​*/*​  Rendered
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb
>
> (0.9ms) Completed 200 OK in 20ms (Views: 6.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
>   md5_dgst.c(78): OpenSSL internal error, assertion failed: Digest MD5
>   forbidden in FIPS mode! Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: I'm not sure you can (at least not as a config option) There seem to be a couple of places where usage of md5 is hard coded, e.g. in ActionView::Digester (which I think is used to manage the view template cache)

Comment: @FrederickCheung that would make it seem as though I cannot use Rails if I am running anything in FIPS mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been addressed in Rails 5.2.  See https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31203.  New apps should be compliant now by default and upgraded ones can use `Rails.application.config.active_support.use_sha1_digests = true`

Comment: LOL.  How did you end up handling it 2 years ago.  Did you monkey patch MD5 OSLT?